# PTIJ: Website hechsherim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Can anyone explain to me how the concept of hechsherim and mashgichim works for websites?  I'm often asked by a website to accept some or all cookies, but most websites don't include a hechsher or even ingredients?  Surely this is a big kashrus problem?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You don't have to eat them. I order stuff from ebay and amazon and there's a new thing nowadays where they send you a little sweet or chocolate. It's not kosher, but it's a nice gesture. I just give them to my neighbours.

Answer (score 12):

It says in Kiddush Levana

> משגיח מן החלונות

Therefore you can only accept cookies if you are using a Microsoft computer or laptop.
There is a debate regarding apple computers, being as apples are kosher.

Comment: But is a MacBook model less than 3 years old orlah?

Comment: What about other devices like Chromebooks, Android devices etc?

Answer (score 3):

That is why it is important to have the right safeguards in place.

We learn this from the Mishkan which we apply to our homes which we call a Mikdash Me'at.

As it says in [Shemos 40:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.40.33?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> ...וַיָּ֣קֶם אֶת־הֶחָצֵ֗ר סָבִיב֙ לַמִּשְׁכָּ֣ן וְלַמִּזְבֵּ֔חַ וַיִּתֵּ֕ן אֶת־מָסַ֖ךְ
>
> And he set up the enclosure around the Tabernacle and the altar, and put up the screen...

So you see, first you set up the safeguards and only then lift up the screen of your laptop/computer. That way you avoid treif cookies!